# Why is quicksort better than other sorting algorithms in practice?

Tags: algorithms, performance, sorting

<sup>This is a repost of a [question on cs.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/3/98) by [Janoma](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/24/janoma). Full credits and spoils to him or cs.SE.</sup>

In a standard algorithms course we are taught that **quicksort** is O(n log n) on average and O(n²) in the worst case. At the same time, other sorting algorithms are studied which are O(n log n) in the worst case (like **mergesort** and **heapsort**), and even linear time in the best case (like **bubblesort**) but with some additional needs of memory.

After a quick glance at [some more running times](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms) it is natural to say that quicksort **should not** be as efficient as others.

Also, consider that students learn in basic programming courses that recursion is not really good in general because it could use too much memory, etc. Therefore (and even though this is not a real argument), this gives the idea that quicksort might not be really good because it is a recursive algorithm.

**Why, then, does quicksort outperform other sorting algorithms in practice?** Does it have to do with the structure of *real-world data*? Does it have to do with the way memory works in computers? I know that some memories are way faster than others, but I don't know if that's the real reason for this counter-intuitive performance (when compared to theoretical estimates).

Comment: Quicksort reputation dates from a time when cache didn't exist.

Comment: "why does quicksort outperform other sorting algorithms in practice?" Sure that's true? Show us the real implementation you are refererring to with this statement, and the community will tell you why that specific implementation behaves the way it does. Everything else will lead to wild guessing about non-existent programs.

Comment: @DocBrown: Many Quicksort (or variants of it) implementations are chosen in many libraries, arguably because they perform best (I would hope so, that is). So there might just be something about the *algorithm* that makes Quicksort fast, independently of the *implementation*.

Comment: Someone has to say this for completeness, so I will:   Quicksort is not (usually) stable.  For this reason, you may not want to use it.  Also, for this reason, your default sort may not be a Quicksort even when that is what you want.

Comment: @Raphael: Often what is called quick sort is actually some variation like intro sort (used, afaik, in the C++ standard library), not pure quick sort.

Comment: The other question that should be asked is why merge sort is popular with library writers. The reason? It's not much slower than quicksort, and it's _stable_ (which matters a lot when you end up resorting data, which is relatively common in practice).

Comment: Quicksort has exactly the same big-O characteristics as mergesort. It's usually considered "faster" than mergesort because it performs more comparisons than merge, but moves data items less often, and for MOST applications, moves are more expensive than compares. I once found myself using mergesort because I was comparing VARIANT structs, and doing the "moves" by swapping pointers in an array...

Comment: @mjgates: No, Quicksort does not have "exactly the same big-O characteristics as mergesort". As the question correctly states, worst-case complexity differs.

Comment: I am shocked no one mentioned Timsort.

Comment: @SeasonalShot I'm shocked you did not read the accepted answer before commenting.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I wouldn't agree that quicksort is better than other sorting algorithms in practice.

For most purposes, [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) - the hybrid between mergesort/insertion sort which exploits the fact that the data you sort often starts out nearly sorted or reverse sorted.

The simplest quicksort (no random pivot) treats this potentially common case as O(N^2) (reducing to O(N lg N) with random pivots), while TimSort can handle these cases in O(N).

According to these [benchmarks](http://timsort4net.codeplex.com/) in C# comparing the [built-in quicksort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148074/is-the-sorting-algorithm-used-by-nets-array-sort-method-a-stable-algorithm) to TimSort, Timsort is significantly faster in the mostly sorted cases, and slightly faster in the random data case and TimSort gets better if the comparison function is particularly slow.  I haven't repeated these benchmarks and would not be surprised if quicksort slightly beat TimSort for some combination of random data or if there is something quirky in C#'s builtin sort (based on quicksort) that is slowing it down.  However, TimSort has distinct advantages when data may be partially sorted, and is roughly equal to quicksort in terms of speed when the data is not partially sorted.

TimSort also has an added bonus of being a stable sort, unlike quicksort.  The only disadvantage of TimSort uses O(N) versus O(lg N) memory in the usual (fast) implementation.

Answer (score 18):

Quick sort is considered to be quicker because the coefficient is smaller that any other known algorithm. There is no reason or proof for that, just no algorithm with a smaller coefficient has been found. Its true that other algorithms also have O(*n* log *n*) time, but in the real world the coefficient is important also.

Note that for small data insertion sort (the one that is considered O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) ) is quicker because of the nature of the mathematical functions. This depends on the specific coefficients that vary from machine to machine. (At the end, only assembly is really running.) 
So sometimes a hybrid of quick sort and insertion sort is the quickest in practice I think.

Comment: + Right. Teachers need to be more aware (and I was a teacher) of the fact that constant factors can vary by orders of magnitude. So the skill of performance tuning really matters, regardless of big-O. The problem is, they keep teaching *gprof*, only because they have to get past that bullet point in the curriculum, which is 180 degrees the wrong approach.

Comment: “There is no reason or pro[o]f for that”: sure there is. If you dig deep enough, you'll find a reason.

Comment: Not completely right, may be true for a lot of algorithms, but not for any other known algo, as you wrote. See my answer.

Comment: What is the "coefficient"?

Comment: @B Seven: to simplify a lot… for an O(n log n) sort algorithm, there are (n log n) iterations of the sorting loop in order to sort n items. The coefficient is how long each cycle of the loop takes. When n is really big (at least thousands), coefficient doesn't matter as much as O() even if the coefficient is huge. But when n is small, coefficient matters – and can be the most important thing if you're only sorting 10 items.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey - a good example is that building the pyramids is O(n) while sorting your photos of them is O(n ln n) but which is quicker!

Comment: @BSeven This of the following tow: `5000*n*log(3000*n)` and `7n^2`. The first is O(n log n) the second is O(n^2) - But which is better for n=10? (The coefficients are: 3000,5000,7)

Comment: There are guaranteed O(n log n) algorithms such as heapsort and mergesort, so in asymptotic worst-case terms Quicksort isn't even equally as fast as the best. But in real world performance, some quicksort variants do extremely well. However saying "the coefficient is smaller" is like saying "it's faster because it's faster". *Why* are the constant factors so small? A key reason is because quicksort is very good in locality terms - it makes very good use of caches. Mergesort has good locality too, but it's *very* hard to do in-place.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey - not necessarily. The more recent pyramids are IIRC bigger than the older ones, so building the pyramids could be anywhere from O(n^2) to O(n^4) depending what grows by a constant factor (height, surface area or volume) with each new pyramid.

Comment: The key thing to consider in the big-O analysis is whether what's being checked is the number of *interchanges* or the number of *comparisons*.  Quicksort tends to do relatively few interchanges compared to other sorts, but significantly more comparisons. In a typical library sort, where the comparisons are done by callback functions and interchanges are just pointer swaps, the comparison measure is much more important.

Answer (score 16):

Quicksort does not outperform all other sorting algorithms. For example, bottom-up heap sort ([Wegener 2002](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439759390364Y)) outperforms quicksort for reasonable amounts of data and is also an in-place algorithm. It is also easy to implement (at least, not harder than some optimized quicksort variant).

It is just not so well-known and you don't find it in many textbooks, that may explain why it is not as popular as quicksort.

Comment: +1: I have run some tests and indeed merge sort was definitely better than quick sort for large arrays (> 100000 elements). Heap sort was slightly worse than merge sort (but merge sort needs more memory). I think what people call quick sort is often a variation called intro sort: quick sort that falls back to heap sort when the recursion depth goes beyond a certain limit.

Comment: @Giorgio: quicksort can be modified in some ways to improve it, see for example here: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/ Did you try that improvements?

Comment: Interesting, can you lave a reference to a book\site to read more about it? (preferably a book)

Comment: @Martin: you mean about Bottom-Up heapsort? Well, I gave a reference above. If you want a free resource, the german wikipedia has an article about it (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/BottomUp-Heapsort). Even if you don't speak german, I guess you can still read the C99 example.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't center only on worst case and only on time complexity. It's more about average than worst, and it's about time **and** space.

Quicksort:

- has an **average** time complexity of Θ(*n* log *n*);
- can be implemented with space complexity of Θ(log *n*);

Also have in account that big *O* notation doesn't take in account any constants, but in practice it does make difference if the algorithm is few times faster. Θ(*n* log *n*) means, that algorithm executes in *K* *n* log(*n*), where *K* is constant. Quicksort is the comparison-sort algorithm with **the lowest** *K*.

Comment: The question was mainly about the average case. It's clear that the asker understands the meaning of up-to-a-multiplicative-constant. The question is, why does quicksort have such a low K in practice?

Comment: @Gilles: it has low K, because it's a simple algorithm.

Comment: WTF? This doesn't make any sense. The simplicity of an algorithm has no relation with its running speed. Selection sort is simpler than quicksort, that doesn't make it faster.

Comment: @Gilles: selection sort is O(n^2) for any case (worst, average and best). So it doesn't matter how simple it is. Quicksort is O(n log n) for average case, and among all algos with O(n log n) avg it's the simplest one.

Comment: @Gilles: other things being equal, simplicity does aid performance.  Say you're comparing two algorithms that each take (K n log n) iterations of their respective inner loops:  the algorithm that needs to do less stuff per loop has a performance advantage.

Comment: @comingstorm: Phrased like that your statement is a tautology, but it does not relate to "simplicity". There are, for example, more complicated variants of Quicksort (case distinctions!) that result in smaller runtime (both in theory and practice).

Comment: It may be, um, simple, but it's not a tautology, and it does relate to "simplicity".  Many clever algorithms which seem like they ought to have a performance advantage turn out not to have one in practice, because the overhead outweighs the cleverness.  Complexity is not the same as overhead, but they are not orthogonal, either.

Comment: @comingstorm That only proves that many people who think they are clever are indeed not. As I said, sometimes more complexity *does* help (google for Yaroslavskiy's Quicksort). So, "simpler is better" is useful advice for programmers, but not a law or even fact.

Answer (score 5):

Quicksort is often a good choice as it is reasonably fast and reasonably quick and easy to implement.

If you are serious about sorting large amounts of data very quickly then you are probably better of with some variation on MergeSort. This can be made to take advantage of external storage, can make use of multiple threads or even processes but they are not trivial to code.

Answer (score 1):

The actual performance of algorithms depends on the platform, as well as the language, the compiler, programmer attention to implementation detail, specific optimization effort, et cetera.  So, the "constant factor advantage" of quicksort isn't very well-defined -- it's a subjective judgement based on currently-available tools, and a rough estimation of "equivalent implementation effort" by whoever actually does the comparative performance study...

That said, I believe quicksort performs well (for randomized input) because it is simple, and because its recursive structure is relatively cache-friendly.  On the other hand, because its worst case is easy to trigger, any practical use of a quicksort will need to be more complex than its textbook description would indicate: thus, modified versions such as introsort.

Over time, as the dominant platform changes, different algorithms may gain or lose their (ill-defined) relative advantage.  Conventional wisdom on relative performance may well lag behind this shift, so if you're really unsure which algorithm is best for your application, you should implement both, and test them.

Comment: I guess the "smaller constant" others relate it to is the one in formal analysis, that is on number of comparisons or swaps. This is very well defined but it is unclear how this translates to runtime. A colleague currently does some research on that, actually.

Comment: My impression was that it was about generalized performance, but I wouldn't count on either.  You're right, though:  if your comparison is particularly expensive, you can look up the number of expected comparisons...

Comment: For the reason you state, talking about overall performance (time-wise) is not meaningul in the general case as too many details factor in. The reason for counting only select operations is not that they are expensive, but that they occur "most often" in the Landau-notation (Big-Oh) sense, so counting those gives you your rough asymptotics. As soon as you consider constants and/or runtime, this strategy is much less interesting.

Comment: A good implementation of QuickSort will compile such that your pivot values remain in a CPU register for as long as they are needed.  This is often enough to beat a theoretically faster sort with comparable Big-O times.

Comment: Different sort algorithms have different characteristics with respect to the number of comparisons and the number of interchanges they do. And @DanLyons note that a typical sort in a library performs its comparisons via user-supplied functions, and keeping values in registers across lots of function calls is pretty tricky.

Comment: "The actual performance of algorithms depends on the platform, as well as the language, the compiler, programmer attention to implementation detail, specific optimization effort, et cetera" this is constant for all algorithms you would implement, therefor irrelevant when comparing algorithms..

Comment: No, it's not irrelevant, nor is it constant.  If you're interested in actual performance, you need to look into the details of the platform you're working on, and be prepared for the overall problem to be fuzzier than the theoretical O() analysis you learned in algorithms class.

Answer (score 0):

Quicksort is fast, but only if you implement it very carefully.

Make sure that an array that is already sorted in correct or reverse order will be sorted quickly. This is a very common case, when an array is sorted twice. There are implementations that check first whether your array starts or ends in a subarray that is sorted in ascending or descending order. If the elements are random, then this will take very little time. If an array is sorted or the concatenation of two sorted arrays, then you can sort it in linear time. If you have n sorted items followed by fewer than O (n / log n) random items, you can sort it in linear time.

Really bad implementations will always choose the first or last element as the pivot, which turns Quicksort into Big-Theta(n^2) if the array is sorted; picking a random element as the pivot will help enormously.

Make sure that the implementation is fast if all or many elements are equal. With k equal elements, bad implementations will take k^2 operations for those elements, so if more than O (sqrt (n log n)) elements are equal, you won't be sorting in O (n log n) anymore.

Fine tuning: Consider the cost of a comparison and of moving elements. You can't avoid n log n comparisons, but you can sort with O (n) moves. If moving is substantially slower than comparing, you can sort an array of array indexes, get the exact order of indices for the correctly sorted array, and permute the elements. This may not be cache friendly, and uses extra storage for indices, so you may only want to do it if a subarray that you are partitioning fits into a cache.

Easier fine tuning: If moving elements is a lot more expensive than comparing, but not excessively: You reduce the number of moves by not picking the median as the pivot, but a bit of the median. So what you can do is pick 4 random elements and use the 2nd smallest or 2nd largest as the pivot. The number of comparisons grows, but the number of moves goes down.

Partial sorting: Sorting may be needed to display items in sorted order. But if you have tons of items, you can't display them all. You can put a million items into buckets according to the first letter, and if you want to display say items 330,000 to 330,025 you check which bucket they are in, and sort the one bucket containing the items you want. This can make things ten times faster.

Two cases where Quicksort is not the fastest by far: 1. Your array was sorted, but its values change slowly over time. Say weather stations sorted by temperature. One minute later the temperatures have changed slightly. Bubblesort might be fastest. 2. Your array was sorted, but a small number of random items has been changed, sometimes massively changed. If you have n items of which k are changed, you can sort them in O (n + k log k) which is linear if k = O (n / log n).